# Is there a way to check if input is letter and number in one textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a month day and year fill up form, and im using vb.net 2012 i need is when i press the save button it will change back color if greater than 12,
This is the code im using

```
If txtMonth.text.trim = "" or IsNumeri(txtMonth.Text.Trim) = False or txtMonth.Text.Trim > 12 then
txtMonth.Backcolor = Color.Red
Else 
txtMonth.Backcolor = Color.White
End if
```

Im getting error in my code saying
Conversion from string "e1" to type 'Double' is not valid
E1 is what i input on textbox, what can i do, to make it completely run without error

Comment: You should pretty much ALWAYS use OrElse rather than Or. You should read the documentation to learn the difference. The same goes for AndAlso over And.

Comment: Apart from that, you should be using TryParse to validate and convert text to a number in one go.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: i use it like this If txtMonth.text.trim = "" orElse IsNumeri(txtMonth.Text.Trim) = False orElse txtMonth.Text.Trim > 12 then but it says the same thing can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Problem Solve the tryParse do it hehe Thank you so much my project is done :D